# How to get expandable objects view as output in VS Code node terminal?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I would like to have collapsible/ expandable objects in the terminal output in VS Code like on the browser console.

Here is an example:

[image: Picture of expandable object in browser console]

In the debug terminal it works only if I toggle a breakpoint before the end of the program, but otherwise I get the error "No debugger available, can not send 'variables'".

So I'm thinking if the functionality is there, there must be a way to get it even without setting breakpoints every time. Right?

Answer (score 2):

Use `console.dir()` instead of `console.log()`.

Use this following example, to display *all* nested objects:

```js
console.dir(yourStuff, { depth: null })
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
"outputCapture": "std"
```

in launch.json